# How to EFFICIENTLY implement multiple custom UITableViewCells with SLIGHTLY different content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having problem managing the UI of my app. The app utilizes UITableView, with multiple prototype cells. 
Everything works well, I have got like:

```
TypeACell.h + m files
TypeBCell.h + m files
TypeBCell.h + m files
etc.
```

I have created prototype cells in my Storyboard's UITableView, and have like 6 of them, each one connected to the specific type of cell.

Thing is, that at least 4 elements of each custom cell, could be reused in each cell.
Let's assume that only 2 elements differ in each custom cell.

For the sake of argument, let's imagine the cells look like this:

```
TypeACell
    row1
    row2
    rowCustomA1
    rowCustomA2
TypeBCell
    row1
    row2
    rowCustomB1
    rowCustomB2
etc.
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath I have something like that:

```
if(array[i] == TypeA){
    TypeACell *cell = [tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:typeAIdentifier]; 
    set row1,row2, rowCustomA1, rowCustomA2;
    display TypeACell
}
else if(array[i] == TypeB){
    TypeBCell *cell = [tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:typeBIdentifier]; 
    set row1,row2, rowCustomB1, rowCustomB2;
    display TypeBCell
}
```

Thing is that using that kind of implementation, I have to modify 12 places in order to make change, that is common for all the cells. I am looking for a way to modify my implementation. I have been wondering whether some Objective-C specific method exists that would help me deal with this nonsense. Could you please provide me with your experience and tips?

Edit:
added cell initialization to each "if". Right now, this is only problem that I can't solve in the implementation based on inheritance.

Comment: Not specific to ObjC but still important to understand: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Why are you iterating over your array? `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` tells you what element you need.

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right, that was just a mistake in pseudocode. Thought of cellForRowAtIndexPath, and wrote "for" instead. However the question about dealing with different identifiers remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you can benefit from inheritance: make a base class with the elements common to all your cell types, then make the individual cell types its subclasses, like this:

```
@interface CommonCell : UITableViewCell
    ... // Common properties
@end
@interface TypeACell : CommonCell
    ... // Properties specific to A
@end
@interface TypeBCell : CommonCell
    ... // Properties specific to B
@end
@interface TypeCCell : CommonCell
    ... // Properties specific to C
@end
```

Now your loop can be changed as follows:

```
for(iteration over array){
    CommonCell *cell = ...
    ... // set common elements
    set row1, row2
    if(array[i] == TypeA){
        set rowCustomA1, rowCustomA2;
    }
    else if(array[i] == TypeB){
        set rowCustomB1, rowCustomB2;
    }
    ...
    display cell
}
```

Comment: I've been thinking about using inheritance, however I do not know how to deal with different cell identifiers. Currently each "if" contains different declaration of cell i.e : if(typeA){ cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ktypeACell]; }

Comment: Got it solved, I added if(..)elseif(..) statement, to determine which identifier to use, and THEN created the CommonCell with the correct identifier. Later in my if's I used [[(TypeACell*)cell rowCustomA1] setText:@"text"] to operate on the needed properties. Thank you, thought that there is some special construction in iOS, but good old inheritance, made the trick :)

Comment: @Michael You could avoid an `if`-`then`-`else` chain with `[[NSClassFromString(@"NameofClass") alloc] init];`

Comment: My datasource for tableview has multiple types of elements inside of it, and I need to determine which one is about to be displayed at the moment hence the necessity of if-then-else. Unfortunately I do not know how to use [[NSClassFromString(@"") alloc] init]; in the described situation.

Comment: @Michael If I understand you right, the purpose of your `if-then-else` chain is to arrive at a decision of what class to create. If your chain of `if-then-else` statements uses some sort of key to look up, you can build a dictionary from your key to the cell class name, e.g. like this:  `NSDictionary *typeNameToCell = @{ @"a" : @"TypeACell", @"b" : @"TypeBCell", ...}`. Then you can do this: `CommonCell *cell = [[NSClassFromString(typeNameToCell[cellKey]) alloc] init];`

Comment: Implemented your suggestion in even more simple way: I changed keys with values in the dictionary that you suggested, which made it possible for me, to use custom cell identifiers like this CustomCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:typeNameToCell[@"TypeACell"]]; Thank you, really cool way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need more than 1 UITableViewCell subclass.

1. Make the properties in the cell as generic as possible: (row1, row2, row3, row4).
2. Have the different looks for each cell only be in the prototypes.
3. You only need to distinguish the different types in your array `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int cellType = array[indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellID = cellType == TypeA ? typeAIdentifier : typeBIdentifier;
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    cell.row1 = …
    cell.row2 = …
    cell.row3 = cellType == TypeA ? … : …;
    cell.row4 = cellType == TypeA ? … : …;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, that is really great way to redesign the implementation of my cells. You made me wonder, which answer (yours or @dasblinkenlight) should be checked as the "correct" as they both are.